# QuickFix/n - Custom fields inside Logon

Tags: c#, quickfix, quickfixn

I'm trying to create an initiator based on QuickFix/n.
My counterpart (server) demand the logon message to carry two custom fields.I already added those to the Data Dictionary, in the Fields as well as in the Logon message.
In the code i can manipulate the message to add the username and password, but i can't find how to load custom fields.

Here are some excerpts from what i've done so far:

*TradeClientApp.cs*

`...`

```
public void ToAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
        {
            QuickFix.SessionSettings settings = new QuickFix.SessionSettings("./initiator.cfg");
            List<SessionID> sids = settings.GetSessions().ToList();
            Dictionary settingsDict = settings.Get(sids.First());
            var appName = settingsDict.GetString("ApplicationName");
            var userType = settingsDict.GetString("UserType");

            if (message.GetType() == typeof(QuickFix.FIX44.Logon))
            {
                message.SetField(new Username("USERNAME"));
                message.SetField(new Password("PASSWORD"));
                message.SetField(new QuickFix.Fields.ResetSeqNumFlag(true));

                //tag 9933
                message.SetField(new RawData(string.Format($"9933={appName}")));
                //tag 20110
                message.SetField(new RawData(string.Format($"20110={userType}")));

            }
        }
```

The **initiator.cfg** file:

```
[DEFAULT]
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=./spec/FIX44.xml
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=USERNAME
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
Username=USERNAME
Password=PASSWORD
TargetCompID=TARGETCOMPID
StartTime=12:30:00
EndTime=23:30:00
HeartBtInt=10
ApplicationName=app-name
UserType=V
SocketConnectPort=446
SocketConnectHost=SERVERHOST
```

Inside the **FIX44.XML**

```
<message name="Logon" msgtype="A" msgcat="admin">
      <field name="EncryptMethod" required="Y" />
      <field name="HeartBtInt" required="Y" />
      <field name="RawDataLength" required="N" />
      <field name="RawData" required="N" />
      <field name="ResetSeqNumFlag" required="N" />
      <field name="NextExpectedMsgSeqNum" required="N" />
      <field name="MaxMessageSize" required="N" />
      <group name="NoMsgTypes" required="N">
        <field name="RefMsgType" required="N" />
        <field name="MsgDirection" required="N" />
      </group>
      <field name="TestMessageIndicator" required="N" />
      <field name="Username" required="N" />
      <field name="Password" required="N" />
      <field name="ApplicationName" required="N" />
      <field name="UserType" required="N" />
    </message>

 <fields>
   ...

   <field number="9933" name="ApplicationName" type="STRING"/>
   <field number="20110" name="UserType" type="STRING" />
 </fields>
</fix>
```

When i try to connect i get this log:

`<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.49=12035=A34=149=USERNAME52=20191008-21:19:41.49856=TARGETCOMPID96=20110=V98=0108=10141=Y553=USERNAME554=PASSWORD10=097`

Using the **RawData** as shown in my example, the message carries *20110=V* as RawData, which is tag 96, which doesn't help me.
I already tried inside **ToAdmin**:

`message.Header.SetField(new StringField(QuickFix.Fields.Tags.UserType, ""));`

or

`message.SetField(new QuickFix.Fields.UserType(true));`

but neither work.

How on earth do you add custom fields to the logon message?

Comment: Did you look at the very bottom of [this page](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html)?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier i checked numerous pages, including this one. i always would get to the bottom and stop at ".GetString" because i couldn't get this line to work. The answer was some pixels below. Classic old me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting the `RawData` data type wrong. That is literally meant for raw data, not for Strings that follow the default encoding.

From the spec:

> string field containing raw data with no format or content
>   restrictions. Data fields are always immediately preceded by a length
>   field. The length field should specify the number of bytes of the
>   value of the data field (up to but not including the terminating SOH).

I am not so familiar with the C# implementation of QuickFIX but you should simply be able to add these fields with the specific tag number, e.g.

```
message.SetField(new StringField(20110, "V"));
```

I hope there are no syntax errors, but you should get the idea.

Edit: I see you are manually setting the ResetSeqNum field on the Logon message. This is discouraged. quickFIX/n should deal with this when you set ResetSeqNum=Y in the settings (you already have that setting).

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much. Also thanks for the tip about the ResetSeqNum.